# Read all Interface into List

Tags: java

How do I convert all `TaskStatusConstant` interface items into one `List<String>` automatically?

```
public interface TaskStatusConstant {

    final static String NEW = "New";
    final static String ACCEPTED = "Accepted";
    final static String REJECTED = "Rejected";
    final static String REASSIGNED = "Reassigned";
    final static String COMPLETED = "Completed";

}
```

Comment: You should use Enum instead

Comment: You cannot do it automatically. You'll need to write the logic yourself.

Comment: The most "automatic" way to do it would be using reflection to load all static strings defined in that class. I would avoid this and do what @JigarJoshi suggested.

Comment: I just don't want to create another class for enum, if there is any changes to this interface, i have to change another class too.

Comment: I second @JigarJoshi's proposal. An enum is the proper way to go. Get rid of this abused interface and refactor your code to use the enum instead. This should be easy to do as you can access the enum's values just like the Strings in the interface. Should you need those exact strings assigned to the enum values take a look at hofmeister's link. As enums are basically classes they can have a constructor and their own attributes, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those information should be represented in an [enumeration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

```
public enum TaskStatusConstant {
   NEW,
   ACCEPTED,
   REJECTED,
   REASSIGNED,
   COMPLETED
}
```

To iterate over an enum in Java use this:

```
for (TaskStatusConstant task: TaskStatusConstant.values()) {
  // do what you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection, for example:

```
    List<String> constants = new ArrayList<String>();
    Field[] fields = TaskStatusConstant.class.getFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        if (field.getType().equals(String.class)) {
            constants.add(field.getName());
        }
    }
    for (String constant : constants) {
        System.out.println(constant);
    }
```

Comment: Btw I agree with you that reflection is not tool for ordinary progarmmers and shall be avoided in most cases. I just wanted to try it for the first time in my 15y+ carier.

Comment: Well, try to run this code yourself, please. Btw I thought that interface has all methods/properties public by default. It would not make sense otherwise.

Comment: I did not notice it was an `interface`. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum TaskStatusConstant2 {
       NEW("New"), ACCEPTED("Accepted"), REJECTED("Rejected"), REASSIGNED("Reassigned"), COMPLETED("Completed");

       private String value;

       private TaskStatusConstant2(String value) {
          this.value = value;
       }
       public String getStatus() {
          return value;
       }
}
```

Just tried this one... Not sure this will work for my other codes :)

Comment: Do it this way unless you really can't use enum for some reason. Here, enum seems the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using enum (recommended, has many benefits)

```
public enum TaskStatusConstant {
           NEW("New"),
      ACCEPTED("Accepted"),
      REJECTED("Rejected"),
    REASSIGNED("Reassigned"),
     COMPLETED("Completed");

    private final String toString;

    private TaskStatusConstant(String toString) {
        this.toString = toString;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return toString;
    }

    public static List<String> valuesAsString() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(TaskStatusConstant c : values()) {
            list.add(c.toString());
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

#### Using reflection (not recommended, it's a hassle, sometimes necessary)

```
public static List<String> valuesAsString()
throws IllegalAccessException {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Field f : TaskStatusConstant.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if(f.getType() == String.class) {
            f.setAccessible(true);
            list.add((String)f.get(null));
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```